# geneplotter installation error

Tags: r, namespaces, bioconductor

I've during the geneplotter (Bioconductor package) installation. I'm using R 2.14 on Linux Mint 9. I think the namespace is responsible for this but I don't know how to fix it ...

Here's the error :

```
> source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
> biocLite("geneplotter")
BioC_mirror: 'http://www.bioconductor.org'
Using R version 2.14, BiocInstaller version 1.2.0.
Installing package(s) 'geneplotter'
Installing package(s) into ‘/home/nicolas/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.14’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
essai de l'URL 'http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.9/bioc/src/contrib/geneplotter_1.31.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1387616 bytes (1.3 Mb)
URL ouverte
==================================================
downloaded 1.3 Mb

* installing *source* package ‘geneplotter’ ...
** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices ...
*** tangling vignette sources ...
   ‘byChroms.Rnw’ 
   ‘visualize.Rnw’ 
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : 
  undefined exports: .__C__file, .__C__connection
Erreur : le chargement a échoué
Exécution arrêtée
ERREUR : le chargement a échoué
* removing ‘/home/nicolas/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.14/geneplotter’

The downloaded packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpO1aY1T/downloaded_packages’
Message d'avis :
In install.packages(pkgs = pkgs, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘geneplotter’ had non-zero exit status
```

Thanks in advance,

N.

Comment: Contact package maintainer ???  There have been changes in namespace handling in 2.14, it's quite likely that some Bioconductor packages haven't caught up ...

Comment: update all packages for the new release, in particular rtracklayer; try `biocLite(character())`

Comment: I updated all packages but the error is still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into this more closely, `geneplotter` [failed to build](http://bioconductor.org/checkResults/release/bioc-LATEST/) for the initial release. So the version you are picking up is the penultimate version. The issue you identify was corrected yesterday, in time for the next build cycle. `geneplotter` should install correctly when it builds correctly, probably at noon PDT; look for version 1.32.1. In retrospect not a SO question; the Bioconductor [mailing list](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/) has a [post facility](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/mailform/) that does not require subscription.